# How can I convert this cURL command to a python script?

Tags: python, curl, post

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Here is the command.

Answer (score 3):

How about this sample script?

#### Sample script :

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"
payload = {
    "client_id": "535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865",
    "client_secret": "qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(res.text)
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that worked for the most part. Now I'm just getting a weird error.

"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.

Comment: @mickolasjae I'm sorry for the inconvenience. As a modification point, please modify from ``res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))`` to ``res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)``, and try again.

Comment: @mickolasjae If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could use os (though it's outdated)

```
import os 
os.system("curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'")
```